# How to create multiple instances of an activity? - revisited

Tags: android, android-activity, expandablelistview, multiple-instances, tabactivity

I want to start multiple instances of the same `(ExpandbleList-)activity` using different parameters, so different data is loaded in the lists. These lists are in different tabs of a `TabActivity`.

So far it works, but when I update the information in one list, then return to the second list and click on one of the items (or change the screen orientation) this list is repopulated with data from the other list.

How can I start the activities so that they don't interfere with each others data?

Comment: P.s. I could probably check each time the array with list contents is used which parameter was given at start-up, but that doesn't seem the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, each Activity will be a new instance.
Did you accidently set "single top" in the manifest for this Activity?
Did you set up static (so, shared) members in the Activity which should not be static?
How you instantiate the "different" Activity's personality; by giving Extras to the Intent?

Comment: So, I didn't set single top in the Manifest, but I did have some static members in my Activity (including the array with list items and the request code used to get the data in a different activity). I have changed these now so that they are not static any more and my ExpandableListViewAdapter now gets it's own copy of the array. Also I made sure that the request code is different for each type of use (so that they don't accidentally grab each others results). And now it works! So thanks a lot!
P.s. Yes I used the extras in the intent to instantiate the different "personalities".

Answer (score 0):

Activity will not be a new instance, that is why they have the resume and pause methods.  I was trying to start a new Intent from a service that was started by a broadcast receiver.  A completely different thread than the Main/UI thread.  Worked fine unless that had already been run by the user then I got the following error for trying to create a new Intent even with the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException:  Only the original thread that created a view heirarchy can touch its views.